# Missing file Error when using send_data() to download pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

Here's a simple one: I can't figure out how to link to a pdf download from a displayed image.  It seems so simple, but I can't get send_data to work.

`send_data()` doesn't text-highlight which seems like the method isn't being recognized.

in my view:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('my_image.png'), 'download_pdf_version') %>
```

in my controller:

```
  def download_pdf_version
    #send_file('#{RAILS_ROOT}/my_pdf.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'attachment')
    send_file('#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/my_pdf.pdf')
  end
```

updated config/routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  ... 
  get "my_controller/download_pdf_version"
  ...
```

I've tried putting the pdf in the /`public`/ directory in the `assets` directory and I've tried so many permutations on the path to the file.  I've isolated my method gets called, but it seems that the path to the pdf file is wrong?

Error screen:

```
ActionController::MissingFile ...
Cannot read file #{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/my_pdf.pdf
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on the "it does not work" part ? What is the result or error ?

Comment: Thank you.  I just added a bit more on the exact error screen I'm getting right now.  I've been reading that the path you need to specify for send_file() is absolute.  Still tinkering with it.